# F.Lux Not Working

Tags: display, color

Recently fluxgui stopped working correctly. The service starts and there is the indicator in the wingpanel, but has no effect. After selecting the color temperature and hitting preview does not change the screen color. Anyone have any idea? Redshift works, but it's unreliable at best and tends to flicker at random times.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
sudo apt --purge remove fluxgui
```

After, delete the files in the folder `~/.local/share/fluxgui`

Reboot, and reinstall fluxgui

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Though it's behaves like this since fresh install. It used to work perfectly. But like many things in elementary, an update broke it. Sometimes it's like being in a rolling distro without the advantages but all the disadvantages haha